# Use ggtext to ggplot graphic but can not display superscript ^

Tags: r, ggplot2, superscript, ggtext

I use this code for display the graphic but -1 can no t display like superscript, can you help
NOTE: I used boxplot groups

```
#install.packages("ggtext")

library(ggtext)

ggplot(pesosip,aes(x=Treatment,y=PESO..gr.,fill=Weight.record))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  ggtitle("C")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("Control (Male)","PTX 60","NCTD 3",
                            "MIX"),
                   labels=c("Control<br>*(M)*","PTX 60 mg kg^-1 <br>*(F)*",
                            "NCTD 3 mg kg^-1 <br>*(F)*","MIX<br>*(M)*"))+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Record",labels=c("Initial","Final"))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown(),legend.position = "top")+
  labs(x="Treatment",y="Weight (g)",fill="Record")
```

superscript for -1

Comment: I think `ggtext` wants `<sup>STUFF</sup>` instead of `^`: https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/articles/introduction.html

Comment: `labels=c("Control<br>*(M)*","PTX 60 mg kg<sup>-1</sup> <br>*(F)*",
                            "NCTD 3 mg kg<sup>-1</sup> <br>*(F)*","MIX<br>*(M)*"))+`